# Can I hide the carat of a textbox using css?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, textbox

I know there's lots of reasons not to do this, but I really need to. I'm using the Jquery UI datepicker and I've styled a textbox to look like a hyperlink. Anyway, everything's working great except that when i click the textbox it has the blinking carat. Is there a way to get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: micah can you post the screenshot of the image please,??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an hidden `input` and show the `a`. When you click `a` it triggers the `input` focus.

**[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7eYxC/1/)**

html

```
<input id="i" type="text" value="select date" />
<a id="open" href="#">select date</a>
```

js

```
$("#open").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#i").trigger("focus");
});

$("#i").focus(function(){
    alert("Open datapicker");
});
```

Not a CSS solution, but it's one way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

```
    function makeCaretInvisible(textboxId) {

  var inputBox = document.getElementById(textboxId);

  var outputBox = inputBox.cloneNode(true);

  outputBox.id=outputBox.name='';

  outputBox.onclick=function(){
    inputBox.setSelectionRange(outputBox.selectionStart, outputBox.selectionEnd);
  };

  inputBox.onkeyup=function(){
    outputBox.value=inputBox.value;
  };

  inputBox.parentElement.insertBefore(outputBox, inputBox);

  inputBox.style.position='absolute';
  inputBox.style.top='-10000px';

}​
```

http://jsbin.com/ihobe4/edit

Comment: if that is the case , why to use javacript or jquery you can do it with just css...right

Comment: I've updated the code, Micah. I initially misread the question.

Comment: No, @gov.  Because what you're basically doing is when you select the first input box, it creates another off screen. As you update the other one, it updates this one, therefore never actually clicking in the box.  There may be a better method as this is a tedious hack, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a hidden `input` and an `<a>` to avoid the issue all together?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="cal_link">select date</a>    
    <input type="hidden" id="cal" />
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#cal").datepicker({
    buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    showOn: 'button'
});
$("#cal_link").click(function() {
    $("#cal").datepicker("show");
});
```

Try it out (obviously, you can style the `<div>` and use whatever `buttonImage` you want): http://jsfiddle.net/s5e6k/